# Strange page reload after getting images back from server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I use React to choose some files in file input and send them to nodejs server as buffer. On server I resize, save the images and send generated links to the client.

Client got the links back and strangely reloads page, the question is why?

React class part:

```
handleClick() {
    const {send, value} = this.props
    const {attachments} = this.state

    if (attachments.length) {
        send(value, attachments)

        this.setState({
            attachments: []
        })
    }
}

addFiles(files) {
    const {attachments} = this.state

    const newAttachments = [...attachments]
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, file => {
        if (newAttachments.length < 10)
            newAttachments.push(file)
    })
    this.setState({
        attachments: newAttachments
    })
}

handleDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    this.addFiles(e.dataTransfer.files)
}

handleFilesSelect(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    this.addFiles(e.target.files)
}
```

Server code part:

```
const saveRoomPhoto = (roomId, avatar) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const relativePath = `images/rooms/${roomId}/${crypto.randomBytes(5).toString('hex')}.jpg`
    const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../public', relativePath)

    gm(avatar)
        .resize(2048, 2048, '>')
        .write(absolutePath, err => {
            err
                ? reject(err)
                : resolve(relativePath)
        })
})
```

Intresting tip: resizing images to small size(eg 100x100) solves the problem